# Ubuntu ZFS or other file system layout question

Tags: raid, zfs

I have a system currently setup as a plex server running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I am in the process of upgrading the server and was wondering about the best way to layout file systems. I was looking at moving to ZFS pools but I wasn't sure that was ideal.

The current machine has media spread across a number of discs. 4x8TB Seagate 5400rpm archive drives and 4x4TB drives (a few different types).

Currently they are all mounted as separate file systems and half are used for backing up to the other half via an rsync script I cobbled together.

One draw back of the current setup is that I need to do a series of mount points for the media, a movies drives, music drive, and Running TV Series and Finished TV series. In particular I would like to consolidate all the TV together but there is more than 8TB of that currently.

The current setup is functional but some sort of more consolidated setup that arranged all of it as one giant "media" drive seems an attractive alternative.

The current mirroring arrangement is desirable to keep in some form and ability to survive a drive failure matters far more than performance.

I would also really like the ability to add new drives to the set up without needing to copy everything off and copy everything back onto a setup.

The new system will be built around an i5 processor and 16GB of RAM.

ZFS looked like it might do the job well. The idea being to build two pools in a mirror setup (RAID-Z if I follow the terminology correctly). The difficulty of any setup here is that I have the mirrors currently but can't repurpose all the drives at once as the data needs to be moved to the new pool in stages. One of the other RAID settings would would if I can extend the pool 1 disc at a time as I copy the data from outside the pool into it and then add the copied disc as a new drive into the pool.

Is there something related to ZFS that makes it wildly unsuitable for the task?

Do people have any suggestions how they would approach such a set up?

Am I better off sticking with the current setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently using ZFS for this use case (i.e. media center storage). I've used it for several years now.

You can indeed configure your ZFS as a mirror:

- Data are copied amongst all disks in the mirror
- The available size is the size of your smallest disk
- So you can mimic an usual RAID mirroring by creating a zpool with X mirrors, each one containing 2 disks.

Or as RAID-Z 1/2/3:

- You can loose 1, 2 or 3 disk depending on the type of the RAID-Z
- The RAID-Z size is limited by the smaller disk, so having 4x4TB and 4x8TB is equivalent to having 8x4TB if all configured on the same grape. So, in your case, it's recommended to create 2 different raid-z of 4 disks each in the same pool.

Also, **ZFS does not support yet adding a disk to an existing RAID-Z**. So if you create a RAID-Z of 4 disks, it would never be able to contain more than 4 disks (but you can upgrade each disk to larger ones for example).

It's also important to know that it requires a lot of CPU/RAM for read/write operations. ZFS is configured by default to be able to use all your free RAM minus 1GB.

For more details, [this document](http://wiki.illumos.org/download/attachments/1146951/zfs_last.pdf) describes how ZFS works, and compares it with usual RAID.

*NB:* If you intend to use ZFS, be sure to create your zpool with `ashift=12` option like this:

```
zpool create -o ashift=12 ...
```

This sets the sector size to 4096B instead of the default 512B. It will greatly improve your performances for your use case.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So it sounds like I would be best off waiting till I can buy a couple more 8TB drives and make two 3x8TB RAID-Z mirrored together. Which is workable.